# Signing groups with embedded signing

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I am using embedded signing and signing groups.
I need a group of people have access to my envelopes through my app.

I'm using envelopesApi.createRecipientView to get the url of the envelope but the url returned by this method doesn't allow any of the group members to sign the document, but when the members of the group receive the email with the url included, it works !

I've noticed that the response of envelopesApi.listRecipients has the field clientUserId = null for all signing group, I don't know why it happens, because I set the value of clientUserId properly when I've created the envelope.

Anyone having the same problem?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do embedded signing with a signing group, only remote signing (Via email).

The reason is that embedded signing assumes you, as the app, knows exactly who is the signer. We (DocuSign) trust you to ensure that person is signing, unlike in a normal situation, where this responsibility is on us.

In a signing group, you don't know who will be signing from the members of the group, and so you cannot show the embedded signing UI until you do. If you know which of the group members will sign - you can do that.

Signing group sends the email to ALL group members and only one can/will sign, you cannot imitate this behavior with embedded signing.

Answer (score 0):

As Inbar says, the DocuSign Signing Group feature only works with remote signers (notified via email or SMS).

But if your application has a number of people who might "grab" an envelope and then work on it, you could implement that via the API and embedded signing.

Here's some ideas to try:

1. Within the routing order of the signers and other recipients, decide which routing number will be your "embedded signing group". Add an embedded "placeholder" signer there (with a userClientId setting). The "placeholder" will cause routing to stop and wait. The "placeholder" can use a fake name and email.
2. Use webhooks so your app is notified when it is time for your signing group to become active
3. Notify all the members of your signing group that an envelope is available. Eg, make a message flash on all of their screens, add to a queue on the screen that your app shows to all of the users, etc. You could show the notification to any number of people via your app. No limits!
4. When one of your people presses a button on your app to "take" the envelope, do the following:
5. Remove the envelope listing from all the other people using your app.
6. Get the lock for the envelope (enter "correct" mode)
7. Change the name and email of the "placeholder" recipient to be the person who "took" the envelope.
8. Create an embedded view for the envelope and present it to the person. (You may need to release the lock first, I'm not sure.)
9. Done! Now the person has the envelope via an embedded signing session.